# How to make element clicked before it hiden from parent on unfocus

Tags: javascript, html, css

I trying to make an simple search field element, i created a plain javascript code down below.

The filter and the focus are as expected with the code, but when i clicked the `grandchild` element, it doesn't nothing, like it even not even being clicked. The element is still right there, it's seem the unfocus on the `<input>` element happend first than the listener on the `grandchild`. Is there a way, how to make the click happend first, or to delay when unfocus?

```js
String.prototype.isContain = function(trg) {
  return (getLength(this.toLowerCase().split(trg.toLowerCase())) > 1);
}

let fieldinput = document.querySelectorAll(".child-1")[0];
fieldinput.addEventListener("keyup", function() {
  let grandchild = document.querySelectorAll(".grandchild");
  for (let x in grandchild) {
    if (grandchild.hasOwnProperty(x)) {
      if (grandchild.innerHTML.isContain(fieldinput.value)) {
        grandchild[x].style.display = "block";
      } else {
        grandchild[x].style.display = "none";
      }
      grandchild[x].addEventListener("click", function() {
        console.log(grandchild[x].innerHTML); // this never executed
      });
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
}

.parent .child-1 {
  padding: 10px;
}

.parent .child-2 {
  position: absolute;
  max-height: 0px;
  top: 100%;
}

.parent .child-1:focus+.child-2 {
  max-height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <input class="child-1" type="text" placeholder="Focus Here">
  <div class="child-2">
    <div class="grandchild">Option 1</div>
    <div class="grandchild">Option 2</div>
    <div class="grandchild">Option 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Several issues

- missing code
- unnecessary use of querySelectorAll when you only want one element
- nested event listener creation - You currently add an event listener to all grandchildren for every key you press
- Non-Dry

```js
String.prototype.isContain = function(trg) {
  return this.toLowerCase().split(trg.toLowerCase()).length > 1;
}

document.querySelector(".child-1").addEventListener("input", function() {
  document.querySelectorAll(".grandchild")
    .forEach(grandChild =>  grandChild.hidden = !grandChild.innerHTML.isContain(this.value))
});
document.querySelector(".child-2").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target.closest(".grandchild");
  if (tgt) console.log(tgt.textContent)
});
```

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
}

.parent .child-1 {
  padding: 10px;
}

.parent .child-2 {
  position: absolute;
  max-height: 0px;
  top: 100%;
}

.parent .child-1:focus+.child-2 {
  max-height: 500px;
}

.hide { display: none }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <input class="child-1" type="text" placeholder="Focus Here">
  <div class="child-2">
    <div class="grandchild">Option 1</div>
    <div class="grandchild">Option 2</div>
    <div class="grandchild">Option 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```